# Angular Form Validation How To Add Nested Form Controls to FormData

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

Here I'm using .net Core And Angular And I'm new to Angular. I implemented my Angular Form Validation Using `ReactiveForm` when I'm trying to upload my file then my file not binding Server Side.

Then I come To know bind my values to `FormData` But I'm not able to bind my nested form values
Here in Attached My StackBlitz Url Please Find the details
Thank You

[StackBlitz](https://angular-6-reactive-form-validation-7a5zat.stackblitz.io/)

Thank You

This is My Eited Code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kry5bh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: you have shared the stackblitz project. not the editable code.please share the editable link.

Comment: so what is your problem there?

Comment: @yash  Here im not able to Binding My Nested Form Controller

Comment: i saw you didnt import ReactiveFormsModule in app module. are you saying about the error?

Comment: @yash im asking how can i bind nested from Values

Comment: Bind to servers side means what you are not able to sent the data to server ?

Comment: @Navitas28 here I'M  not able to send nested form data to server.. reaming all are binding except nested DATA

Comment: I think this bug occurred in your .net project.In your server side do you have a class to accept the request data ? check if it accept a array of skills?